# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener in jquery.nicescroll.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting below error in iPad mode in browser

> unable to jquery.nicescroll.min.js:2054 preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being trated as passive.see https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5093566007214080
>
> NiceScrollClass.cancelEvent @ jquery.nicescroll.mins.js:2054
> self.ontouchstart @ jquery.nicescroll.min.js:1059

I found solution for nicescroll.js but could not get for nicescroll.min.js

Any help will be appricated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The min.js file is just the minified version of the same file. The fix should work for both. However I would say that directly editing the code of a library file is not a good solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/799
this link suggested tochange line 2555.such line is missing in nicescroll.min.js

Comment: Given that the library hasn't been updated in 5 years, then that seems to be your solution, then. I'd suggest finding a new, well supported, library which does what you need though

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how to update library without edit directly?

Comment: You can't, that's the problem :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.